# Compiling for STM32F4 Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, stm32f4discovery

Good Day,

I just bought an STm32F4 and was able to load a sample .hex file located inside:
https://github.com/mechoid9/STM32F4

I had followed instructions from this site:
http://jeremyherbert.net/get/stm32f4_getting_started

And it explained how to code, but it failed to state how to actuaully execute the makefile. I ran it and it gave me a chunk of errors:

```
 SRCS: command not found
 SRCS: command not found
 CFLAGS: command not found
 CFLAGS: command not found
```

The makefile looks like this:

```
# put your *.o targets here, make should handle the rest!

SRCS = main.c system_stm32f4xx.c
SRCS += lib/startup_stm32f4xx.s # add startup file to build
# all the files will be generated with this name (main.elf, main.bin, main.hex, etc)

PROJ_NAME=main

more code goes..
```

I am not even sure how to even execute it to build my hex files etc.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Herbert's website and other blogs helped many people - including me - when starting with STM32F4 development. But most of them assume you are familiar, at least in a beginner level, with GNU Make.

I apologize if I assume in my answer that you are not acquainted with makefiles yet, but if that's the case the answer is incredibly simple: Just use the command 'make' in the same directory where you Makefile is.

I strongly recommend you to get used to read makefiles since there are many useful resources in the web that will require you to tailor makefiles a bit. It will worth the time investment.

TL;DR: make

Comment: Yes, it seems like raaj tried to treat the Makefile as a shell script.  It's not that different conceptually, but the necessary interpreter is not the shell, but rather the 'make' program.  As a guess, on a Mac one would get that by installing xcode.

Comment: You're right. It seems to be mandatory to install "Command Line Tools for Mac OS" only - no need to install the entire XCode. I'd post the entire download link, but since it need to go through Apple authentication after authentication at [https://developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) raaj will need to register himself, if he is not already. Not sure if brew or macports offers a similar Xcode-free make.